# ERROR reports occur when parallelchain synchronize KSM blocks

Tags: parachain, kusama, parachain-collator

```bash
2022-05-24 08:13:38.060  INFO                 main sc_service::builder: [Parachain]  Highest known block at #0    
2022-05-24 08:13:38.060  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate_prometheus_endpoint: [Parachain] 〽️ Prometheus exporter started at 0.0.0.0:9779    
2022-05-24 08:13:38.062  WARN tokio-runtime-worker parachain::bitfield-distribution: [Relaychain] Failed to fetch basics from runtime API relay_parent=0xb0a8d493285c2df73290dfb7e61f870f17b41801197a149ca93654499ea3dafe err=Execution { runtime_api_name: "session_index_for_child", source: Application(Execution(Other("Exported method ParachainHost_session_index_for_child is not found"))) }
2022-05-24 08:13:38.062  WARN tokio-runtime-worker parachain::dispute-coordinator: [Relaychain] error=RollingSessionWindow(SessionsUnavailable { kind: RuntimeApi(Execution { runtime_api_name: "session_index_for_child", source: Application(Execution(Other("Exported method ParachainHost_session_index_for_child is not found"))) }), info: None })
2022-05-24 08:13:38.062 ERROR tokio-runtime-worker parachain::bitfield-distribution: [Relaychain] Our view contains 0xb0a8…dafe, but not in active heads added=0xb0a8…dafe
2022-05-24 08:13:38.063  INFO                 main parity_ws: [Parachain] Listening for new connections on 0.0.0.0:8847.    
2022-05-24 08:13:38.071  WARN tokio-runtime-worker parachain::candidate-backing: [Relaychain] Failed to fetch runtime API data for job err=Execution { runtime_api_name: "validator_groups", source: Application(Execution(Other("Exported method ParachainHost_validator_groups is not found"))) }
2022-05-24 08:13:38.073  WARN tokio-runtime-worker parachain::dispute-distribution: [Relaychain] error=Sender(Runtime(RuntimeRequest(Execution { runtime_api_name: "session_index_for_child", source: Application(Execution(Other("Exported method ParachainHost_session_index_for_child is not found"))) }))) ctx="on FromOverseer"
2022-05-24 08:13:38.076 ERROR tokio-runtime-worker polkadot_node_subsystem_util: [Relaychain] job finished with an error job="bitfield-signing-job" parent_hash=0xb0a8…dafe err=Util(RuntimeApi(Execution { runtime_api_name: "session_index_for_child", source: Application(Execution(Other("Exported method ParachainHost_session_index_for_child is not found"))) }))
2022-05-24 08:13:38.572  INFO tokio-runtime-worker sub-libp2p: [Parachain]  Discovered new external address for our node: /ip6/240e:390:e57:f950:4a6:6409:91fb:8040/tcp/40336/p2p/12D3KooWHJ8XuP92wAG5qgoUTiDbGvgwFbB1WAQpvKxCp77Km5ZN    
2022-05-24 08:13:38.572  INFO tokio-runtime-worker sub-libp2p: [Relaychain]  Discovered new external address for our node: /ip6/240e:390:e57:f950:4a6:6409:91fb:8040/tcp/30346/ws/p2p/12D3KooWJA8i7TCgjBZKcZWnchrMsKN7dFJvrtRSfoE86dPgAPjc    
2022-05-24 08:13:39.085  INFO tokio-runtime-worker sub-libp2p: [Relaychain]  Discovered new external address for our node: /ip4/115.198.90.209/tcp/30346/ws/p2p/12D3KooWJA8i7TCgjBZKcZWnchrMsKN7dFJvrtRSfoE86dPgAPjc    
2022-05-24 08:13:41.105  WARN tokio-runtime-worker parachain::dispute-coordinator: [Relaychain] Received msg before first active leaves update. This is not expected - message will be dropped. msg=ActiveDisputes(Sender { complete: false })
2022-05-24 08:13:41.105  WARN tokio-runtime-worker parachain::dispute-distribution: [Relaychain] error=Sender(AskActiveDisputesCanceled) ctx="on FromOverseer"
2022-05-24 08:13:43.047  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing, target=#12816475 (17 peers), best: #2826 (0xd05d…92e7), finalized #2560 (0x95cd…876e), ⬇ 362.8kiB/s ⬆ 34.9kiB/s    
2022-05-24 08:13:43.063  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Parachain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x1cf1…a1b9), finalized #0 (0x1cf1…a1b9), ⬇ 0.7kiB/s ⬆ 0.6kiB/s    
2022-05-24 08:13:48.048  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing 1073.2 bps, target=#12816475 (25 peers), best: #8192 (0x4b7e…af70), finalized #8192 (0x4b7e…af70), ⬇ 477.8kiB/s ⬆ 26.5kiB/s    
2022-05-24 08:13:48.066  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Parachain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x1cf1…a1b9), finalized #0 (0x1cf1…a1b9), ⬇ 58 B/s ⬆ 60 B/s    
2022-05-24 08:13:53.049  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing 843.2 bps, target=#12816476 (25 peers), best: #12408 (0x79e4…c0ff), finalized #12288 (0xe1b8…1b9f), ⬇ 347.5kiB/s ⬆ 17.2kiB/s    
2022-05-24 08:13:53.066  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Parachain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x1cf1…a1b9), finalized #0 (0x1cf1…a1b9), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2022-05-24 08:13:58.049  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing 611.2 bps, target=#12816477 (26 peers), best: #15464 (0xe8e1…660d), finalized #14849 (0x7ad6…e8e7), ⬇ 409.8kiB/s ⬆ 46.4kiB/s    
2022-05-24 08:13:58.066  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Parachain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x1cf1…a1b9), finalized #0 (0x1cf1…a1b9), ⬇ 61 B/s ⬆ 61 B/s    
2022-05-24 08:14:03.049  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing 1154.2 bps, target=#12816478 (27 peers), best: #21235 (0x16bb…7f18), finalized #20480 (0xa143…9640), ⬇ 405.2kiB/s ⬆ 22.2kiB/s    
2022-05-24 08:14:03.067  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Parachain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x1cf1…a1b9), finalized #0 (0x1cf1…a1b9), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2022-05-24 08:14:08.051  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing 856.8 bps, target=#12816479 (28 peers), best: #25520 (0x311a…0fbf), finalized #25088 (0xbb53…2395), ⬇ 418.9kiB/s ⬆ 27.3kiB/s    
2022-05-24 08:14:08.070  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Parachain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x1cf1…a1b9), finalized #0 (0x1cf1…a1b9), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
......etc
```

I don't know if this affects the operation of parallel chains.